# Is the standard library my best option for Java to load/read and edit/modify and save a html file with no reformatting?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to load/read and edit/modify and save a html file located on my hard drive. I tried **JSOUP**, but it kept reformatting the html file. I want to avoid reformating.

I'm wanting to inject some JavaScript after the `<script>` and before `var deviceReady = false;` in the html file.

Do I need to parse the file?

Should I use default Java? (BufferedReader, FileReader, Scanner)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale = 1, minimum-scale = 1, maximum-scale = 1'/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
<title>LX-XXX-KU</title>
<style type="text/css">#initialLoading{background:url(assets/htmlimages/loader.gif) no-repeat center 
center;background-color:#ffffff;position:absolute;margin:auto;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;z- 
index:10010;}</style>

"

<script>

var deviceReady = false;
var initCalled = false ;
var initialized = false;

function onBodyLoad()
{
 if(typeof window.device === 'undefined')
{
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
else
 {
    onDeviceReady();
 }
}
```

Javasacript I want to add after the `<script>` and before `var deviceReady = false;`

```
`//adds numbers to TOC
window.addEventListener( 'moduleReadyEvent', function ( e )
{
var myText = document.getElementsByClassName('tocText');

for ( var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++ )
{
var getText = myText[ i ].childNodes;
var str = ( i + 1 ) + ' ' + getText[ 0 ].innerHTML;
getText[ 0 ].innerHTML = str;
}
});`
```

Comment: If you want to save the file otherwise unmodified, you'll have to be very careful how you parse it.  Any parser that doesn't pass the text verbatim to you isn't going to work.  Take a look at STAX, part of the standard library https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html

Comment: BTW, jsoup does generally leave the input unmolested, if you turn off pretty-printing. I added an e.g. below. It's simpler to use than the STAX parser IMHO (certainly STAX would work as well, as long as the input was reasonably formed XML or you handled all the errors)

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished like so:

```
File f = ...;
String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(f));
int idx = contents.indexOf(insertBeforeStr);
contents = contents.substring(0, idx) + contentToBeAdded + contents.substring(idx + 1);

// write contents back to the disk.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you turn off jsoup's [**pretty printing**](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#prettyPrint(boolean)) option, and use the [XML parser](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#xmlParser()) instead of the validating HTML parser, the document and all of its text verbatim, including whitespace, is passed through pretty much unmolested, other than syntax fixes for attributes, missing end tags, and the like.

See for example your input on [Try jsoup](https://try.jsoup.org/%7E77bUbeIU02P_c59bbMHQiVVCotA) with pretty-printing off, and using the XML parser, is effectively the same as your original.

The code would be something like:

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<script>\nSomething(); ", "", Parser.xmlParser());
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);

Element scriptEl = doc.selectFirst("script");
DataNode scriptData = scriptEl.dataNodes().get(0);
scriptData.setWholeData(scriptData.getWholeData() + "\nanotherFunction();");

System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Gives us (note that there's no HTML structure automatically created, due to using the XML parser):

```html
<script>
Something(); 
anotherFunction()</script>
```

ControlAltDel's answer definitely works and means you can do it with just the Java base library. The benefit of using jsoup is (IMHO - as the author of jsoup) in this case is that you're not trying to string-match HTML, and won't get caught by e.g. a `<script>` in a comment, or in this case a missing close `</script>` tag, etc. But of course YMMV.

Incidentally, once jsoup 1.14.1 is released (soon!) with the change [#1419](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1419) (which for script elements, proxies text settings into data without escaping), the code will simplify to:

```java
Element scriptEl = doc.selectFirst("script");
scriptEl.appendText("\nanotherFunction()");
```

Comment: I did not see jsoup 1.14.1 to download, but there was version 1.13.1. Where could I get 1.14.1

Comment: I only gave a portion of the HTML to keep the post short. I used the try JSOUP http://try.jsoup.org/~v5EyaCDR_rwwj9r--WvB-DiccFc     It adds closing tags after color:#ffffff;position:absolute;margin:auto;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;z-index:10010;}</style> towards the top of the document. We are using software that produces this html file, so I only want to inject the additional code without changing anything else. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JamesParker, thanks for that detail. I have updated the answer to also use the XML parser. Unlike the default HTML parser which parses like a regular browser does, the XML parser doesn't enforce HTML tree rules. Also, 1.14 isn't released yet (sorry for typo in answer); would like it to be in the next week or so. But the e.g. works for 1.13.

Comment: Can I use the XML parser on a file that from the hard drive? " File input = new File("C:\\Academics\\Lesson_Production\\" + lesson + "\\index.html"); "